# How does *, *:after, *:before work?

Tags: css, stylesheet

I have seen the following in some stylesheets and, I am ashamed to say but I do not know what that stands for and how it works, I only know how it affects the website in browser preview, could you please try and explain this ?:

```
*,
*:after,
*:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

I also used it in a my website cause apparently, with this, my website arranges better in page with it but I added a flexible grid gallery and if I have the above code in my CSS, it automatically puts a padding in between my images, if I remove it, it doesn't.

That is the main reason I am curious about it :)

Thank you

**PS:**

Also , it seems that if I remove the :

```
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
```

...I fix the space between the images problem...hmm

Comment: The trick lies at `box-sizing: border-box`: http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Comment: Yes, but the thing is that if I remove only the first *, my images don't get the same padding. That's what's curious to me

Comment: As far as I know `:after` and `:before` require the `content` to be specified (even an empty string), otherwise there won't be any effect to the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` is CSS selector for all elements.

But remember you should use `::before`, and `::after`.

This:

```
div::before,
div::after{
    content: "text";
}
```

create two pseudo elements in every `div`. Like this:

```
<div>
    <::before>text</::before>
    Ordinary content of div.
    <::after>text</::after>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/Chovanec/pen/FhvaK

Comment: Ok, I know how to use the :before and :after tags but the thing is, what's with that * ? If I remove only the first *, from the css code and I keep the 
*:after,
*:before
...My grid will not gain that padding I mentioned about, it's strange cause that padding in between the grid images is not specified anywhere in my CSS but if i have that first *, in the CSS, the padding appears.

Comment: with * you set padding 0 to all elements. If you remove it your elements get default padding.

Comment: that's what's strange, it sets it to 0 but in the browser it gave it a 20px paddint that isn't mentioned anywhere in my CSS :)) but now that I have removed the **box-sizing: border-box** from my css, everything is arranged the way it should be.

Comment: @Alin That 20px padding is browser's default styles. That's why we always normalize or reset (I personally prefer the former) our CSS.

Answer (score 0):

It is a part of the element you don't normally see, but you can style it. Common examples are the little arrow element.

E.g.

```
p:after {
    content: "AFTER!";
}
```

HTML:

```
<p>Some sentence</p>
<p>Some sentence too</p>
```

Will display as :

```
Some sentenceAFTER!
Some sentence tooAFTER!
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Tn7GQ/

And as for the asterisk(`*`), it means everything literally. As `div > *` means every child of element `div`

Comment: Ok, I know how to use the :before and :after tags but the thing is, what's with that * ? If I remove only the first *, from the css code and I keep the 
*:after,
*:before
...My grid will not gain that padding I mentioned about, it's strange cause that padding in between the grid images is not specified anywhere in my CSS but if i have that first *, in the CSS, the padding appears.

Comment: Oh! The asterisk! It means everything literally. `div > *` means every children of a `div`

Comment: Ok, thanks, but now that i understand that, I have removed the **box-sizing: border-box** from my css, everything is arranged the way it should be. But strange how the **border-box** put by default a 20px space between my images...

Comment: It is a good practice to add border-sizing, you can read something here: http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/‎